# Выделение памяти под массив

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм, память, memory

Излазил весь интернет (включая этот сайт), но так и не нашел однозначного ответа на свой вопрос.
Задача. Пользователь вводит последовательность чисел, когда вводится 0, последовательность заканчивается. Работаю на чистом Си, поэтому векторы не предлагать :). Дело в том, что динамическое выделение памяти все равно работает так, что мы узнаем, какой размер хочет пользователь, а потом выделяем память (кстати не понятно, почему нельзя спросить размер (n), а потом выделить в стиле int arr[n], зачем тут динамика?). В моем случае, даже, грубо говоря, сам пользователь не знает сколько элементов там будет. Захотел ввел 2 элемента, захотел 1000. Не могу придумать элегантное решение проблемы. Либо выделять память с запасом (совсем не красиво), либо нашел вариант с перевыделением памяти дин. массива в цикле (тоже грабли какие-то). Как поступить? Неужели без c++ векторов не обойтись?
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Выделять память с запасом. Но небольшим :)
Как в векторе из C++.

Выделяете, скажем, под 4 элемента. И отслеживаете - сколько выделено, сколько занято. Когда приходит очередной элемент, а выделенное все занято - делаем `realloc` памяти, в 2 раза большей, и пишем туда.

Получается да, с небольшим перерасходом. Но не более чем в 2 раза, зато амортизированная сложность вставки - O(1) (т.е. в среднем один элемент перезаписывается не более чем один лишний раз).

Answer (score 0):

Список это классика:

```
struct elem {
 double num;
 elem * next;
} ;
```

Пришло число, делаем **new elem** удлиняем список. Не надо, удаляем.